# Flutter Await not waiting

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, async-await

Why won't the program wait for the function to return the list before going to the print statement?

I think it's because I made the forEach loop async but I need it to be async to get the newSummary which is a Future.

```
Future syncToCloud() async{
  final List<Map<String,dynamic>> _events = await events();
  print(_events.length);
}
  
  
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> events() async {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('data');
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> newMaps=[];

  maps.forEach((element)async{
    Map<String, dynamic> newElement = {};

    if(element['summary']!=''){
      newElement['summary'] = await newSummary(element['summary']);
      print(newElement['summary']);
    }
    else{
      newElement['summary'] = element['summary'];
    }
    newMaps.add(newElement);
  });
  
    return newMaps;
}
  

void main()async{
  await syncToCloud();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing your `return [{'hi':5}]` in a callback which wouldn't work. You should await the Future.delayed then return the List like this `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));`.

```dart
Future syncToCloud() async{
  final List<Map<String,dynamic>> _events = await events();
  print(_events.length);
}
  
  
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> events() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  return [{'hi':5}];
}
  

void main()async{
  await syncToCloud();
}
```

Comment: Yup sorry this was just a minimum reproducible example and I made a mistake. Let me edit the post and add the actual code

Comment: Okay sure. i'll be waiting

Comment: Did you try using `For` loop instead of forEach?

Answer (score 3):

Please replace the following

```dart
  maps.forEach((element)async{
    Map<String, dynamic> newElement = {};

    if(element['summary']!=''){
      newElement['summary'] = await newSummary(element['summary']);
      print(newElement['summary']);
    }
    else{
      newElement['summary'] = element['summary'];
    }
    newMaps.add(newElement);
  });
```

with this

```dart
  await Future.wait(  maps.forEach((element)async{
    Map<String, dynamic> newElement = {};

    if(element['summary']!=''){
      newElement['summary'] = await newSummary(element['summary']);
      print(newElement['summary']);
    }
    else{
      newElement['summary'] = element['summary'];
    }
    newMaps.add(newElement);
  }));
```

Comment: This works too! But changing the forEach to a for loop also worked and was a bit shorter.

Comment: Using this exact code thrown this error: 'This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.' for `forEach` of a `List`.